# SQL Network Length Calculation Lon/Lat

Tags: sql, postgresql, geospatial, postgis, openstreetmap

I currently have an Azure postgresql database containing openstreetmap data and I was wondering if there's a SQL query that can get the total distance of a way by using the lat/longs of the nodes the way uses.

I would like the SQL query to return way_id and distance.

My current approach is using C# to download all the ways and all the nodes into dictionaries (with their id's being the key). I then loop through all the ways, grouping all the nodes that belong to that way and then use their lat/longs (value divided by 10000000) to calculate the distance. This part works as excepted but rather it be done on the server.

The SQL I have attempted is below but I'm stuck on calculating the total distance per way based on the lat/longs.

*Update:* Postgis extension is installed.

```
SELECT current_ways.id as wId, node_id, (CAST(latitude as float)) / 10000000 as lat, (CAST(longitude as float)) / 10000000 as lon FROM public.current_ways
JOIN current_way_nodes as cwn ON current_ways.id = cwn.way_id
JOIN current_nodes as cn ON cwn.node_id = cn.id

*output*
wId node_id latitude    longitude
2   1312575 51.4761127  -3.1888786
2   1312574 51.4759647  -3.1874216
2   1312573 51.4759207  -3.1870016
2   1213756 51.4758761  -3.1865223
3   ....

*desired_output*
way_id  length
2   x.xxx
3   ...

**Tables**
current_nodes
    id
    latitude
    longitude

current_ways
    id

current_way_nodes
    way_id
    node_id
    sequence_id
```

Comment: The C# approach is wrong too. Instead of rolling your own, use a spatial library like NetTopologySuite/ProjNet4GeoAPI that takes care of projections, spatial reference systems, etc. Without this, the distances you calculate will be wrong. EF Core uses NetTopologySuite to load spatial data from PostgreSQL and SQL Server.

Comment: Spatial support in the database itself is added by the PostGIS extension

Comment: `grouping all the nodes that belong to that way and then use their lat/longs to calculate the distance` sounds like you have a line (linestring) stored as individual points instead of using [a standardized form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) understood by spatial libraries and systems. A spatial library could tell you the length of the linestring directly. More advanced functions could tell you whether multiple lines intersect, or which are the closest ones etc

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The C# approach works fine. You have to divide the values by 10000000 to get the true values and then use some complex maths to get the true distances. It's more about doing it on the server instead.

Comment: I've updated the SQL and results as another SO topic showed be how to cost values. Thanks again.

Comment: Whether on the database or in C# the approach is the same. Use the correct spatial features. Check the link I provided and search for PostGIS - *that's* what provides the spatial SQL features. Search for NetTopologySuite, *that's* what allows you to load spatial data from a database with EF Core.

Comment: Assume I've worked with spatial data before, I know about the math and projections, and unless you take care of it (that's what the spatial reference systems do), the distances will be wrong

Comment: Perhaps what you really need is an OSM to WKT converter before importing the WKT into PostGIS

Comment: I didn't assume you had not worked with spatial data before. I've triple checked the C# version, it works. I will add that I didn't code it manually - that maths beyond me. I don't control the table design as that's done by OpenStreetMap contributors. I saw the postgis comment above and just finished installing it. Will search around SO to see how it could be used.

Comment: Check the PostGis site and the documentation, not SO. SO isn't documentation. The *actual* documentation shows how to install, what the functions are eg [ST_LENGTH](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Length.html). OpenStreetMap's docs contain [a guide on using PostGIS with OpenStreetMap data](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PostGIS), with pointers to conversion tools

Comment: I've been checking the PostGIS website as well but SO may contain an implementation method that has been done before and better examples. The problem with the PostGIS examples, is that they've hard coded in the points into the queries i.e. "SELECT ST_Length(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(743238 2967416,743238 2967450,743265 2967450,
743265.625 2967416,743238 2967416)'". They'll be a link on the site with non-hardcoded versions but I've not seen it yet. I'll get back later with any progress. Thanks again.

Comment: In that sense your own question is hard-coded. You can just pass field names instead of the values. You *don't* need to store strings when you can store shapes. In fact, spatial indexes work on shapes, not text

Comment: I disagree. In the example I posted from PostGIS, the strings had been hardcoded rather than retrieved via some sort of SQL loop with items grouped by way_ids.

Comment: Why should anyone use any loop when you can just read the field value? You don't use a loop when you use SELECT. Did you check the link to OpenStreetMap's own wiki page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much simpler should you also had the `geometry` in your table, i.e. the actual point instead of just the coordinates, or, even better, the actual lines.

That being said, here is a query to get what you are looking for:

```
SELECT w.way_id,
    ST_Length( -- compute the length
      ST_MAKELINE( --of a new line
        ST_SetSRID( --made of an aggregation of NEW points
          ST_MAKEPOINT((CAST(longitude as float)) / 10000000,(CAST(latitude as float)) / 10000000), --created using the long/lat from your text fields
        4326)  -- specify the projection 
       ORDER BY w.sequence_id -- order the points using the given sequence
       )::geography --cast to geography so the output length will be in meters and not in degrees
    ) as length_m
FROM current_way_nodes w
    JOIN current_nodes n ON w.node_id = n.node_id
GROUP BY w.way_id;
```

Comment: I changed the "JOIN current_nodes n ON w.node_id = n.node_id" to "JOIN current_nodes n ON w.node_id = n.id" and it worked perfectly! Thank you!